# python - requests - how to POST "few stages" forms

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, python-requests

I know how to post a form, but I have no idea how to post "few stages" forms. This is what I mean: `First stage` - you fill the form 
 `Second stage` - form is shown as preview (you cannot edit data, only click Back or Next button).
`Third stage` - they offer some marketing to bump up your ad (you have 2 buttons, Cancel or Send) 
I tried to do that in session, anyway, here is my code:

```
import requests 

payload = {'log': "MY_LOG", 'pwd': "MY_PASS"} # data for log in in Stage 0

url = "http://..._id=3" 
url2 = "http://.../wp-login.php"

with requests.Session() as session:
    res2 = session.post(url2, data=payload) # login page - passed successfuly
    payload2 = {'adcontact_phone': '123321123', 'adtitle': 'TEST TEST',\
 'addetails': 'TEST TEST'} # fields name and data
    res = session.get(url, params=payload2) # 1st stage (fill the form)
    res = session.post(url, data=payload2) # 2nd stage (preview the form)
    res = session.post(url) # 3rd stage (promotion)
```

Few words of explanation in terms of first `res` has `.get` and `2,3` have .`post`, because, according to `Dev console`, first form had method `GET` and 2nd and 3rd stage had `POST`. 
I hope it is clear enough now. Let the brainstorm begin :D

Comment: Tried that as well: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tonybaloney/2cad188f86dc0dae1d8523a2bb7f9796/raw/979e914a8078557b6651753a2f22755dbf30a9e5/requests_example_5.py

Comment: In this line you used `res = session.get(url, data=payload2) # 1st stage (fill the form)` but you know the prameter should be `params=payload2`. Did you try that?

Comment: @SIM Yes, I did try that. However, thank you for valuable note, I updated code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I scraped URL with bs4, and apparently, there were couple hidden input fields that I had add to payload with some value. 
At the end, it worked, so I am satisfied.
Thanks everyone who was involved in this question, and for tips.